# Involutory vs Involutary: Are both terms correct?

Tags: definitions, involutions

I have seen references for both terms, apparently referring to the same notion of a "self-inverse function".

Do both of these terms really mean the same thing? Is one a misspelling of the other? Is one the older version of the other? Are both still used? If they are the same, why having two terms then? Which one should I use when writing an academic paper?

Comment: https://www.indiatoday.in/education-today/grammar-vocabulary/story/list-of-words-with-alternate-spellings-1579528-2019-08-10

Comment: Not on that list @GerryMyerson. But https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/involutory#:~:text=Noun,i.e.%2C%20that%20has%20period%20two.

Comment: you especially mean the corresponding adjective, since the noun itself is "involution"

Comment: @darij, well done. My link was only meant to show that sometimes there's more than one (correct) way to spell a word.

Comment: We can expect any mispelling to be involuntary.

Comment: As @darijgrinberg perhaps implicitly pointed out, Wiktionary does not recognise 'involutary', and there is surely no great authority.  (I have certainly never seen 'involutary', and would assume it was a typo if I did.)

Comment: on which one to use, involutory. The other one really does seem a version of voluntary; Latin voluntarius... they relate involute  to involve "envelop, surround; roll into, wrap up"

Comment: I think "involutive" is actually the word I would use most of the time.

Comment: In Latin the suffix *-orium* is often used to form names denoting places with a function: e.g. dormitorium, a room for sleeping. The suffix *-arium* is used to denote places where thing are kept: e.g. armarium, closet for weapons and tools. This has nothing to do with the question, I suppose

Comment: @PietroMajer, so we could call a group with lots of involutions involutary? (But I find the example 'armarium' interesting, since I would call it an 'armory', so I guess that word came *via* some other route.  (EDIT: Aha, *via* Anglo-Norman, from which both it and 'armuré' derive.)  I thought first of 'vivarium'.)

Comment: Yes, and Italian *armadio* also comes from *armarium* (but we only put clothes in it)

Comment: MathSciNet yields over a thousand hits for *involutory* and only about 50 hits for *involutary*. Without looking carefully at how the word is used, I would guess that *involutary* is just an alternative spelling for *involutory*. (If there really is supposed to be a mathematical distinction between the words then that surely would rate as one of the most confusing choices of terminology in mathematics.)

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Wow, that's a paradox I haven't seen before! Cool.